# Should a "password reset" link be valid after changing email?

Tags: passwords, password-reset

Here's the scenario:

Your account has multiple active “password reset” links out in the world. They expire after 24 hours, and after you change your password.

Instead of changing your password, you then change your account email. Should the password reset links still be valid? Is it a security risk to not invalidate them?

Comment: should you not also only have a single valid password reset link?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would argue that yes, you should invalidate them. The email change may be because the email account is compromised. And there is no harm in invalidating them, as the user is clearly logged in and can just request another one if they need to.

That being said, it is much more important to send a verification email to the old mail before you allow a change and if the user lost access, send instead an undo link valid for at least 7 days (ideally more). Otherwise, you risk account theft.

Lastly, if you support 2FA, you should not allow resetting both factors using just email.

PS: Also you should not allow changing mail for a period of time after password reset.

Comment: So you say the email account may be compromised, but then suggest sending an email change undo link?

Comment: @multithr3at3d I suggested that only if the owner cannot access the confirmation link. And yes, I think it is better to end up in a stalemate between the attacker and the owner than let the account be stolen entirely in some cases. You can make a more elaborate system if you want to solve this, or just enforce 2FA.

Comment: working on 2FA, but yes, we're requiring multiple points of verification already.

Comment: To clarify, by stalemate I mean, that the attacker can access the account but he can't decouple it from the original email, so if the owner recovers the email by for example presenting ID or something like that to google, he can recover his other accounts.

Comment: @jdubjdub By writing my last comment, I realized I should add: Also you should not allow changing mail for a period of time after password reset, so that a compromised email can not result in account being taken over entirely.

Comment: I would also argue that you should only have one valid password reset link at a time. If a new link is requested, invalidate the old one because they're telling you they didn't get the first one. So who knows where it ended up?

Comment: @nbering Well, it can be done. But it is not really necessary. If your mails may end up in hands of attackers, you have a whole different set of problems.

Comment: I think your last 3 points are extremely important.  Everyone uses email as a verification method.  Depending on what your site is, you may even want to disable extremely sensitive transactions when something as drastic as an email address change happens.  (Financial transactions for instance)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be able to change your email address if you don't know the
password.  If you lose both the password and access to the email of record,
you're screwed.

Comment: yep, we're requiring verification and password to confirm email change already. no way to change email if you don't have access to both emails and password.

Comment: I think that's too extreme - people lose access to particular email addresses all the time.  If they do, they'd be locked into the existing password forever.